# Why HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED, HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED?

Tags: winapi

MSDN - "`ShellProc` Function", "`RegisterShellHookWindow` Function":

```
 HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED   => A top-level, unowned window has been created.
 HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED => A top-level, unowned window is about to be destroyed.
```

But:

we'll get `HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED`/`HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED` also when only do Hide/Show (or set/cancel `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`) to any top-level unowned window (with taskbar button).
Why? Taskbar button isn't "true" window, isn't it?

This question primarily for MS insiders here.

Comment: It really means "a top level window is eligible to appear on the taskbar" and "a top level window is no eligible to appear on the taskbar." These are the things a shell cares about.

Comment: Note the missing values, no HSHELL_WINDOWHIDDEN or HSHELL_WINDOWRESTORED.

Comment: Well, you got your answer from the MS insider. Good for you!

Comment: @Raymond Chen: I think the absurdity of this terminology (destroyed/created) is obvious to anyone, and the only thing that can somehow compensate for it - an additional explanatory text (maybe - your text above) in the MSDN/DDK

Comment: The terminology is from the standpoint of the taskbar. If a window is hidden, it may as well be destroyed as far as the taskbar is concerned.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: Well, if these comments will be included in MSDN/SDK - this will prevent confusion for others in the future.